# Center a UIActivityIndicatorView for a UITableViewController in the window, not in the table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a `UIActivityIndicatorView` to my table view in the interface designer. I am trying to center it in the middle of the screens using the following:

```
   override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        self.activityView.center = self.view.center
    }
```

But it always seems to be sitting too 'low' on the page, it appears to be centered in the middle of the UITableView, not in the middle of the window like I want (ie. It is getting pushed down by the navigation bar etc)

Answer (score 3):

Using auto layout, you can use `layoutMarginsGuide` to get the right center X, Y anchor in both `UITableView`s and `UICollectionView`s:

```
activityView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
activityView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
activityView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to set the activityView frame to the *bounds* of the view. Setting just the center doesn't work because the y value for the tableView frame is negative.

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    self.activityView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    self.activityView.frame = self.view.bounds
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
  self.activityView.center = self.view.window?.center
```

If not then how about this:

```
let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
self.activityView.center = CGPoint(x: screenSize.width / 2, y: screenSize.height / 2)
```

It's a bit longer but handles In-Call Status Bar well.